# Implementing iNotifyPropertyChanged for a simple Person class crashes VisualStudio XAML designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I have this peculiar problem. All I have is a single textbox in my XAML, bound to a `Person` class. When I implement `iNotifyPropertyChanged` in `Person` class the Visual Studio XAML designer crashes  and if i just run the project I get **StackOverflow** exception.

When I ***remove***`iNotifyPropertyChanged` everything works fine and textbox gets bound to the FirstName field in Person class.

This is my XAML, nothing fancy, simply a databound textbox

```
<Window x:Class="DataBinding_WithClass.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:DataBinding_WithClass">
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid" >
        <Grid.Resources>
            <c:Person x:Key="MyPerson" />            
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource MyPerson}"/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" Width="150px"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is my Person class, in the same project:

```
public class Person: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            { return FirstName; }
            set
            {
                FirstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }            
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }  

    }
```

I have tried

Restarting Visual Studio 2012(running on windows 7 Home Premium 64Bit)

Starting a new blank project - Same problem

Its so strange, without iNotifyPropertyChanged everything is fine , but then my textbox won't get updates as the **FirstName** in my **Person**class changes....

Have you come across this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You implemented the class improperly.  You need a backing field:

```
private string firstName;
public string FirstName
{
     get { return this.firstName; }
     set
     {
         if(this.firstName != value)
         {
            this.firstName = value; // Set field
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
         }
     }
}
```

Right now, your getter is getting itself, and the setter sets the property itself, both of which will cause a `StackOverflowException`.